# $addFields not accepting arrays in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am stuck in a problem where I have a field which is sometimes string and sometimes the output of that field is in array so how can i tackle that in $addField query

I am sharing my mongo query code

```js
db.ledger_scheme_logs.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            "type":{ $in: ["add","edit"]},
        }
                
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "trail_beginning": {
                  $substr: [ "$metadata.schemes._trail", 0, 36 ] 
            }
        }  
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "trail_beginning":"$trail_beginning"
            },
            "count": { $sum: 1 }, 
            "items": { $push: "$$ROOT" }, 
        }
    },
     {
        "$sort": {
            count: -1
        }
     }
])
```

In this query the "$metadata.schemes._trail" here schemes is in array in some array of objects and because of that I am getting mongo error -> "message" : "can't convert from BSON type array to String" so how can I solve this type of problem any help with example would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, what behavior do you want when it is an array? Do you want to transform the $substr transformation to all of the entries in the array or just pick one or skip it altogether? Something else? Need to know what you are looking for before we can advise on how to accomplish it

Comment: No actually the field on which i am using $addFields -> $metadata.schemes._trail" the .schemes in some array of object in the whole collection of ledger_scheme_logs is in array so how can i apply logic so that it can accept array as well as string

Comment: That doesn't answer the question which is: What do you want the database to _do_ when processing a document that has an array? Should it apply the same type of transformation to each entry of the array? Is it correct to assume that it is an array of strings?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bigger and trickier question here is about what behavior you would *like* the system to have rather than how to actually make the database do it. There's a closely related topic around (consistent) schema design that naturally follows.

To directly answer your question, you can use [the `$cond` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to conditionally calculate the new `trail_beginning` field based on the data type of the source document currently being processed. An example would be something like:

```
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "trail_beginning": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              {
                $type: "$metadata.schemes"
              },
              "array"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$metadata.schemes._trail",
              "in": {
                $substr: [
                  "$$this",
                  0,
                  3
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "else": {
            $substr: [
              "$metadata.schemes._trail",
              0,
              3
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Using two sample documents with different schemas yields the following as demonstrated in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2VzFOG3JDRP):

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "metadata": {
      "schemes": {
        "_trail": "ABCDEFG"
      }
    },
    "trail_beginning": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "metadata": {
      "schemes": [
        {
          "_trail": "HIJKLMN"
        },
        {
          "_trail": "OPQRSTU"
        }
      ]
    },
    "trail_beginning": [
      "HIJ",
      "OPQ"
    ]
  }
]
```

Taking a glance at the rest of your pipeline though, I *suspect* (but can't say for sure) that this isn't actually what you want to do. This is because the subsequent `$group` will use the entire array of values to do the grouping, but I'm (again) guessing that you want to group based on individual values.

If my assumptions are correct, then logically what you really want to do is `$unwind` the array first *before* you do the substring transformation. This will correct the subsequent grouping logic and, as a side effect, it will also eliminate your problem of having different possible input types during the `$addFields` stage. Your full pipeline would look something like this:

```
db.ledger_scheme_logs.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            "type":{ $in: ["add","edit"]},
        }
                
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$metadata.schemes"
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "trail_beginning": {
                  $substr: [ "$metadata.schemes._trail", 0, 36 ] 
            }
        }  
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "trail_beginning":"$trail_beginning"
            },
            "count": { $sum: 1 }, 
            "items": { $push: "$$ROOT" }, 
        }
    },
     {
        "$sort": {
            count: -1
        }
     }
])
```

[Playground demonstration (using a shorter substring) here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BmIThkJFq6i).

This works because `$unwind` will [treat non-array field paths as a single element array](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#non-array-field-path). However, having a discrepancy in the schema may frequently result in you having to put in special conditional logic to account for the difference in various places in the application. Consider simplifying development by making the schema consistent (converting the non-arrays to arrays with single values).